# How do I ask in a neutral fashion?

Tags: questions

I want to ask a colleague if a letter has already been sent, because I want to make some changes to it.
Is it okay if I ask: "Have you sent that letter?"

I want to ask in a neutral way. I am not sure because I have a feeling that if I ask:"Have you...?" it sounds like I expect them to do something, which is not the case.I just need the information.

Comment: You might say: If you haven't yet sent the letter to X, would you allow me to make some changes to it (to alter/modify/amend it).

Comment: @Ronald Sole Thank you, but I'd like to know if "Have you sent the letter?" sounds neutral.

Comment: Some, particularly those prone to being offended, may infer an accusation in "Have you sent the letter" even if one is not intended. The words themselves do  not imply an accusation. So it is technically neutral, but it may not be interpreted neutrally. This is really a question about psychology and human interactions rather than English. Follow Ronald Sole's advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have you sent that letter?

is perfectly fine. You might consider:

> Have you sent that letter yet?

to make it even more neutral because it doesn't imply that you expect that the letter was already sent.

Or, just say what you mean:

> If you haven't sent that letter yet, I'd like to make some changes to
>   it.